# Difference between cutoff frequency and break frequency

Tags: frequency, education, cutoff-frequency

what is the difference between cutoff frequency and break frequency?
Maybe the first refers to the attenuation of the frequency response module of a \$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\$ factor compared to the maximum value of the frequency response module? Whereas the break frequency refers to each point of the frequency response module in which there is a discontinuity?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In my 35 years with analog electronics I have never before heard the term *break frequency* before. Maybe I would have a clue if you provided a link to where this is mentioned.

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia][1] article on Cutoff Frequency the break frequency and cutoff are equivalent. They're usually taken at the 3dB attenuation point of the filter, but any other attenuation can be specified. [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutoff_frequency

Comment: [This wiki on control theory](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Bode_Plots#Break_Points) also says "break points are sometimes also called "break frequencies", "cutoff points", or "corner points"."

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that break frequencies are frequencies where the slope of the magnitude (in a Bode plot) changes.

So a break frequency corresponds to either a pole or a zero in the transfer function.

For a 1st order system the break frequency is equivalent to the cutoff or corner frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Cutoff frequency and break frequency are not well defined terms. You should look to the context to clarify them. Often they are used interchangeably for the -3dB frequency of a filter between the passband and the transition band, but not always.

Break frequency is sometimes used for the corner frequency of a 'broken' integrator, that is an integrator with an extra R in series with the C, to 'break' its slope back to flat at a high enough frequency. It is also used when measuring noise processes, any point where the spectrum slope changes tends to get called a break frequency.

See also corner frequency and edge frequency. More loose terms that are defined by their context.

Comment: Hi @Neil_UK, if the the break frequency refers to each point of the frequency response module in which there is a discontinuity. Thus it is different to the cutoff frequency of a Bode plot with two real coincident poles (in this case the attenuation is not -3 dB, but -6 dB at the frequency in which there are the two poles)?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Always check the context, never try to over-interpret what you think a loose term is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a course on control engineering and the two terms are defined as follows:

- ***cutoff frequency*** - the frequency at which the amplitude ratio of the system is 3 dB lower than its amplitude ratio at 0 rad/s.
- ***break frequency*** - the frequency of the *break point* in the amplitude ratio curve.  This is the point at which the two asymptotes of the curve meet.  At this point, the curvature of the phase curve changes sign (the inflection point).  For a first order system, this occurs at -45 degrees.

As mentioned by Mario, note that in the case of a first-order system, the cut-off frequency is the same as the break frequency as illustrated below:

[image]

(Sorry about the French plot labels. *Rapport d'amplitude* means amplitude ratio.)